# DAX Create a measure that returns only one value based on another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to create a measure that will fill the whole Column within the filter context using only the value from SALES column where PRIMARY = true

That needs to be happening within the filter context and the report will be filtered by KEY column, that comes from another table and also by Year and Month that comes from the time table.

| KEY | NAME | PRIMARY | SALES | MEASURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | true | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | B | false | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | C | false | 3 | 10 |
| 2 | D | false | 15 | 80 |
| 2 | E | false | 5 | 80 |
| 2 | F | true | 80 | 80 |

Could anyone translate these requirements to DAX?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your column `PRIMARY` is type `boolean` you can use the following calculated column.

### Calculated Column

```
MEASURE = 
VAR SelectedSales = [SALES]
VAR SelectedKey = [KEY]
VAR GetSelectedSales =
    MAXX ( FILTER ( 'Table', [PRIMARY] = TRUE () && [KEY] = SelectedKey ), [SALES] )
RETURN
    IF ( [PRIMARY], [SALES], GetSelectedSales )
```

### Output

| KEY | NAME | PRIMARY | SALES | MEASURE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | True | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | B | False | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | C | False | 3 | 10 |
| 2 | D | False | 15 | 80 |
| 2 | E | False | 5 | 80 |
| 2 | F | True | 80 | 80 |